# Angular material radio button checked from Input()

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have following html file

```
<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu" class="mat-menu-panel-max-width-none">
<mat-radio-group #radioGroup>
<div *ngFor="let item of items, let i=index">
      <mat-radio-button color="primary"
       [value]="item.value"
       [checked]="item.selected"
       class="mat-menu-item"
       (change)="handleSelection(i)">
   {{item.name}}
  </mat-radio-button>
    </div>
</mat-radio-group>
 </mat-menu>
```

And ts file.

```
  import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
  @Component({
    selector: 'item-selection',
    templateUrl: './item-selection.component.html',
 })
export class ItemsComponent {
 @Input() items: any;
 @Output() electionHandler = new EventEmitter();

 constructor() { }

 handleSelection(id) {
 electionHandler.emit({id:id});
 }
 }
```

Here are steps my code is doing:

1. Select a item from the menu.
2. The result is sent to ngrx store.
3. new Input values, items, are set to "item.selected=false" by observable selector.
4. After this, I still see the item is selected. The intent is to reset all items unselected after each action.

What is wrong?

Comment: I would change your Title to include the fact that you are using angular material

Comment: Good point. changed.

Comment: Avoid not to create a variable of the same name as an object property. `electionHandler.emit({id:id});` here, `id` is property and another `id` is variable passed in function.

Comment: Point taken although it is not related what the question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to manually manage the 'checked' state of the radio button. I would personally try to leverage the native HTML functionality and give the radios the same 'name' value of the same value or if your using Reactive Forms, the formControlName property will also accomplish the same thing. And they 'check' and 'uncheck' themselves as the user selects from the form.

Comment: I need to reset all radio buttons to "unchecked" after each selection. This is my requirement because the Input(), items, changes  from observable feed in the parent component.